# What does it mean "to have your feet on backwards"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

I came across [the following saying](https://youtu.be/ZrFQJ0zTZjE?t=49):

> The people who use this tool have their feet on backwards. That way they think they are walking forward, but are really walking backward.

What is the meaning of *"having your feet on backwards"*? It looks like some idiomatic expression, but I couldn't find it. Is it something like *look backwards* or *self-deception* or *fall behind*? Or does it literally mean *feet pointing backwards*?

Comment: I've never heard this expression, but the source you're quoting explains the meaning. "I can't find anything about this idiom, is it common?" would be a fair question, but "What does it mean?" is totally redundant.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you Unfortunately, I am not fluent enough in English to interpret this expression without ambiguity. When I try to visualize a situation, I come across at least 3 idioms to describe it in my language. I'm not sure which one is more appropriate, if any. So I'm looking for help to understand it better.

Comment: I wonder whether the sentiment he's quoting actually originated in another language in which this is a common idiom. After all, the inventor of Linux was Finnish...